# How do I reflect Java version 10 in my build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, java-10

I am making an IntelliJ project of Serenity BDD that will use Java 10. The exact project I am using is built from the maven command, (Using option 3 for just Selenium-Junit):

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=serenity
```

So far I have corrected for the JAXB exception when building/running in Java 10 with the following dependencies in my build.gradle

```
compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0'
compile 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0'
compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'
```

I have also installed the Java 10 Jdk (jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin), and pointed my project to that Jdk. I've also found instruction to update my Gradle to version 4.8, and have done so as well

I'm trying to handle any other compatibility issues, and I'm trying to understand the gradle dependencies process better. With my entire build.gradle posted below, **What else do I need to change to ensure that my build.gradle is helping to maintain Java 10?**

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
}



buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.8.3")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:1.8.3'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:1.8.3'
    compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0'
    compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:1.2.5-rc.11'
    testCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7'
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
}
gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
```

Comment: do you have jdk 10 in your machine ? @user

Comment: Yes. I have installed the Java 10 Jdk, and pointed my IntelliJ project to the 10.0.1/bin. I've also followed instructions to update my gradle to 4.8. I'll add those to my question above

Comment: Then you can try adding that to build.gradle it should work @user